# Linux: id: cannot find name for group ID 999

Tags: linux, bash, group

When I try to run a new bash instance `[egg@localhost ~]$ bash`

I receive `id: cannot find name for group ID 999`

In `/etc/group` there is no group with that Id #. Where is this ID being referenced from?

Comment: Looks like something in your bash startup scripts is calling id; what do you get if you type `id`?

Comment: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r

Comment: Why does that look like output from the root user instead of the "egg" user?

Comment: @JeffSchaller ahh yes, I ran it by accident as root `uid=1000(egg) gid=999 groups=999,1000(seqw) context=unconfined_u:` where do I change that gid 999?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you created the user egg with uid 1000 and assigned group id 999 to it, but somehow the name of the group has not been written to `/etc/group`. Maybe the group egg should have id 999 instead? That's the convention, anyway.

Comment: there is no group named egg in my system anymore but before there was. Right now the user name is egg and the group no longer exists

Comment: Run `grep egg /etc/passwd` and I bet it says something like `egg:x:1000:999:Egg:/bin/bash`. The 999 is the primary group id associated with the user egg. Bash complains because the group is missing in `/etc/group`.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your bash startup files is calling `id -gn` (or something similar to that), which asks the `id` command to look up the name of your primary group, which isn't listed in /etc/group.

Perhaps you used to have a group named `egg` that had GID 999; you could look for that with: `grep ^egg: /etc/group`. If it's not there, you could add it: `sudo groupadd -g 999 egg`.

Perhaps you meant to use a different GID when you created the `egg` account; if there is an `egg` group in /etc/group, but with a different GID -- say, 1000 -- then you could fix it with: `usermod -g 1000 egg` (or `usermod -g egg egg`).

Comment: I rebooted this morning and suddenly Im not running into the problem anymore. I will try the fix if it comes up again.