# How to fix "cannot find name for group ID xxx"

Tags: ubuntu, group

I have read [Linux: id: cannot find name for group ID 999](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355362/linux-id-cannot-find-name-for-group-id-999) but that does not answer my problem.  The following is what I got (the username ABC and group name NAMEX are fictitious, I did adduser NAMEX, upon creation the group name NAMEX was created automatically)

When I logged in as user ABC and typed *"groups ABC"* I got:

```
ABC : ABC adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd git NAMEX
```

But if I typed *"groups"* instead I got:

```
ABC : ABC adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev groups: cannot find name for group ID 515
515
```

*grep 515 /etc/group* returns nothing

*grep ABC /etc/group* gives:

```
adm:x:4:syslog,ABC
....
ABC:x:1000:
git:x:509:ABC,NAMEX
NAMEX:1002:user1,user2...,ABC
```

touch filename.txt failed due to Permission denied:

-rw-rw-r-- 1 NAMEX NAMEX 1234 Dec 1 17:01 filename.txt

I tried removing ABC from group NAMEX with *gpasswd -d* and adding back with *usermod -a -G*, that did not help.

How can I fix?

Comment: First, try to log out and then log in again with a new completely new session. Regarding the file, check the actual `gid` of the file (you could use `stat`). By the way, notice that your second `groups` also didn't show groups `lxd` and `git`. Last thing, check your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, if it only uses local files for groups and users or if there's also nis or ldap or some other map services.

Comment: stat gives me a gid of 1002 as expected.  The second groups broke after printing plugdev.  But /etc/group shows that plugdev has a gid of 46, lxd has a gid of 116, not gid 515 which is the complaint of unknown group. /etc/nsswitch.conf shows group: files systemd.  Nothing like nis/ldap in that file